# any api to get geo location by ip, that relies on a database table and ranges

Tags: java, mysql, database, postgresql, geolocation

I need a table to find the geo location of a person. I used maxmind api algorith and a table given which had numeric numbers (representing ips when the user ip is also converted to an integer).

The table had start and end column to determin the range in which the the ip lies. range determined the location.  Now that maxmind has start colulmn int = > 30 digits and same as end column. (previous versions had start = 9 and end = 9 digits and it was easy to make ints or bigints ) . now with > 30 digits , its hard to even store.  http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ has cvs files.

Question: 1. Is that ok? 2. is there a better alternative that anyone used with confidence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - 
https://github.com/tvondra/geoip
I am using this to do geoip lookup and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this- [IP INFO DB](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php)

I feel this as good